# Why Can't access .net web service methods from ajax, jquery mobile?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, cordova, jquery-mobile

What is reason of problem??? i tried a lot of different way but couldn't access web services's 'hello world' method. i couldn't find reason of problem. My struct is like below.

WebService :

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

JavaScript :

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"                  type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"        type="json/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();

      $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:49182/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        sucess: function() { console.log('response.responseText'); },
        error: function() { console.log('error'); }
      });    
  </script>
</head>
```

Console always gives *error* message.

Comment: are you testing this from your desktop computer or from phonegap application?

Comment: In mean in this case? If you are testing it from a phonegap application you cant access localhost. If this is the case replace localhost with an ip address of your server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your `success` spelling. Besides, you need to catch the error in the error call.

Something like :

`error: function(obj){console.log(obj)};`

It'll give you a better insight as to where you might be going wrong.

Comment: i fixed it but result didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Becoz, you are trying to use soap based webservice like restful service. Change the service to RESTful to use like this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38035/Build-ReST-based-Web-Services-in-NET-C

More reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd203052.aspx
http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer